# jekyll-ga set up for jekyll

Tags: google-analytics, jekyll

I am at the moment starting a new jekyll project. I have from now created a new project inger (jekyll new inger). So I have the default tree of my project. I am trying to set up all the plugins I want to use.
 
The first one is Google Analytics plugin (jekyll-ga). I followed the tutorial at https://github.com/developmentseed/jekyll-ga.
I followed all the following steps
 
Set up a service account for the Google data API

```
-Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/ and create a new project.
-Turn on the Analytics API and accept the terms of service
-Go to API Access on the left sidebar menu, create a new oauth 2.0 client ID, give your project a name, and click next.
-Select Application type: Service account, and click Create client ID
-note the private key's password. It will probably be notasecret unless Google changes something. You'll need to enter this value in your configuration settings.
-Download the private key. Save this file because you can only download it once. Copy it to the root of your Jekyll repository. Safety tip: To protect this file, add its file name to your .gitignore file and to the exclude list in your _config.yml file
-Note the Email address for the Service account. You'll need this for your configuration settings and in the next step.
```

So I have the following page in my google page (https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=inger-analytics)
[image]

The last step is the following : Log into Google Analytics and add the service account email address as a user of your Google Analytics profile: From a report page, Admin > select a profile > Users > New Userhttps://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/provision/?authuser=0#provision/SignUp/)
 I have the following page
[image]
And the sign up button leads me to a form where I must enter information about the site that will use for my site. I don't recognize the instruction of the tutorial (https://github.com/developmentseed/jekyll-ga).
Thank you for your help

Comment: This project is for API access to retrieve already collectd data from a property, is that really what you want ? Because it sounds like you rather want to start tracking your new website, which really just requires you to include a bit of JacaScript to your template.

Comment: Hello Eike and thank you for your answer. Yes indeed, I want to start tracking my new website to display a counter of page visited for some pages of my site. Do you mean that there is a javascript solution for this ? Anyway, I am very interested in what Google analytics can provide as information and may be use it. What do you mean by : This project is for API access to retrieve already collectd data from a property ? Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Google Analytics collects data from websites via a javascript integration and stores it on the Google servers in a "property" that is identified by a unique tracking id. GA has an API that allows you to access the collected data programmatically, e.g. to create automated reports. The project you are using is for accessing aggregated data from the Google servers via that API. If you want to track your website go to the admin section, property settings (middle column), tracking information, tracking code, and copy the snippet that is provided there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Eike. I think I am going to read onlin tutorials to implement it. How can I accept your comments, as it isn't an answer post ?

Comment: Please, if you're still interested on this, you can check my jekyll-ga-v2 version that implement everything in a more simple way: https://github.com/uta-org/jekyll-ga-v2